# Shall I use block or attirbute when designing a Terraform resource?

Tags: terraform

Context: I'm developing a terraform provider.

I can see that some of the providers (like AWS) use an [attribute](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dx_connection_confirmation) (e.g., `connection_id`) when referencing ID:

```
resource "aws_dx_connection_confirmation" "confirmation" {
  connection_id = "dxcon-ffabc123"
}
```

whereas others use *blocks*:

```
resource "aws_dx_connection_confirmation" "confirmation" {
  connection {
     id = "dxcon-ffabc123"
  }
}
```

Is there a specific pattern around it? From what I can see,

1. Use *block* if there're mulitple kinda enum values (`bar`, `bar_2`) and only one of them can be specified:

```
resource "aws_foo" "temp" {
  bar {
     id = "dxcon-ffabc123"
  }
  // bar_2 {
  //   id = "abcde"
  //}
}
```

2. Use *block* to group multiple related attributes:

```
resource "aws_devicefarm_test_grid_project" "example" {
  name = "example"

  vpc_config {
    vpc_id             = aws_vpc.example.id
    subnet_ids         = aws_subnet.example.*.id
    security_group_ids = aws_security_group.example.*.id
  }
}
```

3. Use *block* when there's a plan to add more attributes to the object that block *represents*:

```
resource "aws_dx_connection_confirmation" "confirmation" {
  connection {
     id = "dxcon-ffabc123"
     // TODO: later on, `name` will be added as a second input option that could be used to identify connection instead of `id`
  }
}
```

I found [Attributes as Blocks](https://www.terraform.io/language/attr-as-blocks) doc but it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Usually it's not something you should be worried about as Terraform will abstract that away. The documentation is pretty clear in most cases and setting different attributes in a wrong way will result in an error.

Comment: @MarkoE sorry for the confusion, I'm speaking from a perspective developing a provider (not using).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the direct comparison here is between an argument (attribute) with a Terraform `map` type value (as distinguished from Golang `map`, which can also be used to specify a Terraform `block` value), and a Terraform `block`. These are essentially equivalent in the fact that they allow passing key value pairs as values, but there are some differences. Here is a bit a of a binary decision tree for which to use:

1. Is the ideal Terraform value type a `map` or an `object` (i.e. should the keys follow a naming schema, or can the keys be named almost anything)?

map: attribute
object: block

2. If the value is changed, does that force a Delete and Create, or it is possible to instead Update?

DC: usually block
U: usually attribute

3. Is there another resource in the provider that could replace the usage in the current resource (different API usage) e.g. in your example above would there be another resource exclusively devoted to assigning the connection?

yes: usually block
no: usually attribute

4. Is the value multi-level (multiple levels of key value pairs), or single level?

single level: attribute leads to better code because simpler and cleaner
multi-level: block leads to better code because nested blocks

There may be other deciding factors I cannot recall, but these will hopefully guide in the right direction.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more about "follow a naming schema"?

Comment: Basically if the keys are allowed to be named anything reasonable by the developer, or if only specific keys with specific names are allowed. For example, in AWS tags are a map with keys that can be anything reasonable, but nested security group or ebs volumes have specific keys with specific names.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing an entirely greenfield provider, and so you don't need to remain compatible with any existing usage, I would suggest considering using the [Terraform Plugin Framework](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/framework) (instead of ["SDKv2"](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/sdkv2/sdkv2-intro)) which is being designed around the type system and behaviors of modern Terraform, whereas the older SDK was designed for much older Terraform versions which had a much more restrictive configuration language.

In particular, the new framework encourages using the attribute-style syntax exclusively, by allowing you to declare certain [attributes](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework@v0.6.0/tfsdk#Attribute) as having [nested attributes](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework@v0.6.0/tfsdk#NestedAttributes), which then support most of the same internal structures that blocks would allow but using the syntax of assigning a value to a name, rather than the nested block syntax.

The original intent of nested blocks was to represent the sense of declaring a separate object that happened to "belong to" the containing object, rather than declaring an argument of that top-level object. That distinction was murky in practice, since underlying APIs often represent these nested objects as JSON arrays or maps inside the top-level object anyway, and so the additional abstraction of showing them as separate objects ends up hurting rather than helping, because it obscures the nature of the underlying data structure. Particularly if the physical representation of the concept in the API is as a nested data structure inside the containing object, I think it's most helpful to use a comparable data structure in Terraform.

Many uses of nested block types in existing providers are either concessions to backward compatibility or constraints caused by those providers still being written against SDKv2, and thus not having the ability to declare a structured attribute type -- such a concept did not exist in Terraform v0.11 and earlier, which is what SDKv2 was designed for.

The plugin framework does still support declaring blocks, and there are some situations where the nested item really *is* a separate object that just happens to be conceptually contained within another where the block syntax could still be a reasonable choice. However, my recommendation would be to default to using the attribute syntax in most cases.

---

At the time I'm writing this, the Plugin Framework is still relatively new and its design not entirely settled. Therefore when considering whether to use it, I suggest to consult [Which SDK Should I Use?](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/which-sdk) in order to make an informed decision.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it's still in beta:

> Important: HashiCorp is currently developing providers against the framework, but it is still early in its development cycle..

Comment: Yes, the "What SDK Should I use?" document describes in detail what it means for the framework to be under active development. it's up to you to review those tradeoffs and decide which path makes sense for your goals.